# Excluding Mock Datasource In Maven Profile

Tags: java, maven, mockito, maven-plugin

I have a java backend project that includes services to import data from a database. While working on new features, I sometimes need to deploy and run the code on my local machine. Since I don't actually want to connect to the production db while running experimental code, I set up a mock datasource class using Mockito.

The Mock datasource works fine and does what I want when running locally. The problem I'm running into is that I don't want to include that class and its associated dependencies when doing a production deployment. I added an `<excludes>` section to the configuration section of maven-compiler-plugin. I added the Mock specific dependencies to a 'local' profile section. When I actually try to do a compile using maven however, I get compile errors on the mock datasource class that was supposed to be excluded. I'll post the relevant snippets from my .pom file below. I've tried putting the excludes statement in a specific profile and in the 'default' as shown below. Any help with the would be greatly appreciated.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
        <config>config.dev.properties</config>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>          
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.5</version>            
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    ...
 </profiles>


<build>
    <finalName>order</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>

            <configuration>

                <excludes>
                       <exclude>com/tura/order/guice/mock/**</exclude>
                 </excludes>
                 <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simpler alternative, you could configure an alternative version of your app to be run from the src/main/test source directory instead of the normal directory.
You would also remove the profile and only declare the mockito dependency with the scope test (adding test).
This way, you could launch your app on your computer but this code and mockito would not appear in the final build.

I think it would be a lot simpler IF you can easily configure your app to be run from the test but I don't see why it would be otherwise. Usually, avoiding dealing with Maven profiles is considered good practise if there are alternative ways.

EDIT: following your question...

So first, make sure mockito is defined with the "test" scope in you pom. Like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then your code should not compile anymore as it is under src/main/java and needs Mockito.

Transfer your code into src/test/java/ where it will be able to benefit from the test dependencies (thus Mockito).
You have to know that test dependencies and testing code  (in src/test/) will not be part of the final jar. So this is what you want.

And I forgot to say that the code in src/test/ may be whatever you like: unit test tests, applications with a main(..) methods.

The only tricky part may be to make your code work from the tests. But test code "sees" the main code (the opposite is not true) so you will have to call main code and pass it your mock, where your mock is instantiated in the test code.

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not sure that solution would work for this project, but I might give it a shot if I can't find a better way. Could you point me to a tutorial or example somewhere that explains how to set up a project like you described?

Answer (score 0):

Altough I like Francois Marot's answer, this other choice is cleaner (tough more complicated): Split your current project into several ones:

- One project containing the **core** code of the application: It must publish pure APIs with no dependencies.
- Another project, which must have a dependency on the core, and include the mockito infraestructure as well as your "local" environment facade.
- The last one, if necessary, must have a dependency on the core, and add the proper infraestructure and classes for the "production" environment (depending on the complexity, maybe you could decide to include this one into the core itself).

In this way, you will package your code into 100% reusable libraries, and make one distribution for each required target environment, so that no one of them will be polluted with code aimed for the other target environments.

And the POMs will become simplier and won't need profiles.